# Improving Performance without Joins in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have 3 tables.

```
 - Tab_active(Contains active details )(Contains 30 million records)

 - Tab_apr(Contains customer details for april) (contains 7 lakh
   records) 
 - Tab_may(Contains customer details for may) (contains 7 lakh
   records)
 - Tab_jun(Contains customer details for june) (contains 7 lakh
   records)
```

The table structure is the same for all the tables

```
CustNo Revenue
1000    54.55
```

Now I write a procedure to calculate

```
[(Revenue for June)/(Avg Revenue for Apr,May)-1]
```

for which I require who are active for 3 months(June,Apr and May) and also those who are present in Tab_active.

Considering the size of active customer records,using a join will degrade performance.
Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what "and also those who are active" means.  Does that mean that you want a row returned for every customer in `tab_active` even if those customers don't exist in any of the three other tables?  If so, what is the logic you want to use?  If there is no revenue in June, should the procedure return 0?  Or `NULL`?  If revenue for April or May is missing, should the missing month be ignored or should it be assumed to have a value of 0?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I simply mean, I want records for customers who are present in all the three tables.

Comment: Why (do you think that) joins will degrade performance?

Comment: So, you only want a row returned if the customer appears in all four tables?  Is it possible that a customer would appear in the `tab_apr`, `tab_may`, and `tab_jun` tables and not also appear in the `tab_active` table?

Comment: Ya Justin, there are chances but the probability is low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of one way to do this without a join, but I can't guarantee it'll be faster:

```
select sum(revJun) / (sum(RevMay)*0.5 + sum(RevApr)*0.5 - 1)
from (select CustNo, sum(revJun) as revJun, sum(revMay) as revMay, sum(revApr) as revApr,
             count(*) as NumActiveMonths
      from ((select Custno, Revenue, 'Now' as which, 0.0 as RevJun, 0.0 as RevMay, 0.0 as RevApr
             from tab_active
            ) union all
            (select Custno, Revenue, 'Jun', Revenue as RevJun, 0.0 as RevMay, 0.0 as RevApr
             from tab_Jun
            ) union all
            (select Custno, Revenue, 'May', 0.0 as RevJun, Revenue as RevMay, 0.0 as RevApr
             from tab_May
            ) union all
            (select Custno, Revenue, 'Apr', 0.0 as RevJun, 0.0 as RevMay, Revenue as RevApr
             from tab_Apr
            )
           ) t
      group by CustNo
     ) t
where NumActiveMonths = 4
```

I don't know that this will be faster.  You'll have to experiment.